# correct syntax for setting one variable for two IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variable

```
var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth();
```

and want to modify it to include `#slides2 li` as well. Do i have to write two vars and use them in their respective functions or is there a way to include both IDs in a single line?

I am doing this because I have two divs (that toggle) containing two different slide carousels and am trying to share as much of the scripts as possible.

// EDITED to extrapolate //

i'm missing something simple here, i just know it. the first div works no problem, the second just won't work. should i use classes instead? (that may be a dumb question, but i'm VERY new to JS)

there is quite a bit of code and i couldn't get the jsfiddle working so i just posted a dev doc to our production site.

(url deleted)

// EDIT //

nevermind, the problem was with the css, not the script. adding `clear: both` to `#slides ul, #slidesTwo ul` put them all on a separate line. they were all floating left outside of the `ul`

Comment: You can include multiple selectors, but the question is what is your expected behavior in that case?

Comment: You can include two ID's in the jQuery selector but you'll only get the outerWidth() of the first one

Comment: In addition to Peter's response you can also use the .add method.

Comment: I believe jQuery's `outerWidth()` function only gets the first matched element: `Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.` http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: that said, it sounds like i should be using separate vars for each slide carousel? if the two widths are different the script won't work will it?

Comment: @kristina Or perform a loop with a common class.

Comment: i edited the original question to expand with full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var item_width = $('#slides:visible li,#slides2:visible li').outerWidth();
```

Comment: I think it will always only return the width of the first element.

Comment: It will, but as you can read in question `because I have two divs (that toggle)`

Comment: But toggle what? Width? Height? Visibility? Something else? I guess you assumed mutual exclusive visibility and that this line will be executed whenever the "toggle" occurs, but there is not enough information in the question to come to this conclusion.

Comment: thanks for this. i was going to get it working with individual variables first, then test this out but i can't get the stupid thing working at all now! i posted the page in question in my original post... i just know i'm overlooking something small. i've been looking at this thing for too long.

Comment: you post whole HTML,CSS,JS and query "please help". That doesn't works. Do some research at your own, and if you need more help please make another question

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. The problem turned out not to be the script at all, but the CSS. For the record, though, I always do extensive google searching before asking a question here. But for someone who is learning, sometimes you don't know what you don't know so wider questions are best. It's difficult to answer a question without code and sometimes posting the worker page is better than posting snippets.

Comment: @kristinachilds I am really happy to hear you found the solution. Don't take it wrong, but sometimes googling and looking for answer at your own is much better than asking for help at SO. I've spend LOT of time looking for many answers using google :) Howver I always try my best :) It's nice you have found the proper answer for your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of the `outerWidth()`s of your selected elements...

```
$('#slides li, #slides2 li').map(function() { return $(this).outerWidth(); });
```

`outerWidth()` will only ever return a single `Number` (or `null`).

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a jQuery object referencing both "slides" by using a comma:

```
var item_width = $('#slides li,#slides2 li').outerWidth();
```

However, you might find that's not what you're looking for because it will only give the outer width of the first element matched<sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)</sup>.

So, even though it's more than just one line, maybe what you're looking for is:

```
var item_width = 0;
$('#slides li,#slides2 li').each(function () {
    item_width += $(this).outerWidth();
});
```

While you could more simply use:

```
var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth() + $('#slides2 li').outerWidth();
```

The former version of the code allows you to more easily expand the code later. And as others have suggested, you might consider assigning a common class to each of your slide `<li>`'s (such as 'slideItem') and then use the following code to get a total width for all the slides, regardless of how many there may be:

```
var item_width = 0;
$('.slideItem').each(function () {
    item_width += $(this).outerWidth();
});
```

Now, it's possible you're looking for the maximum width, not the total width, in which case the code is easily altered to suit your needs:

```
var max_width = 0;
$('.slideItem').each(function () { //modify the selector to suit your needs.
    max_width = Math.max(max_width, $(this).outerWidth());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify selecting two different slides, it's recommended to make sure they share a common class. In this case, try adding the class `slides` to both of them.

```
var $allSlides = $('.slides');
```

Since `.outerWidth()` will only return the width for the first element in the set, you might need to iterate over the elements and perform the same action.

```
$allSlides.each(function(index, element) {
    var $this = $(this),
        outerWidth = $this.outerWidth();

    doSomething($this);
});
```

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski because the width is not assumed to be the same for both carousels. I didn't write a loop to get the first value, as I'm sure you understand, but to perform the same action of all of the matched elements.

Comment: why so hard? `$('.slides:eq(1)');`